# am I tracking Debian Stable or Testing?

Tags: linux, debian

When I installed Debian, I clearly wanted to track Testing. a bit after that though, I installed Firefox from the unstable repo, not thinking too much :) I wonder if I am tracking unstable or testing now (I started having a few problems with my install, this is why I am asking). The following is the current content of my  `/etc/apt/rsources.list`:

```
# Debian testing repo
deb http://debian.ludost.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.ludost.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

# Debian testing security repo
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main contrib non-free

#Mozilla repo
deb http://http.debian.net/debian unstable main

# Opera repo
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
```

What do you guys think?

Cheers,
H.

Comment: I suspect you are probably tracking [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) mixing releases tends to make a huge mess unless you are very deliberate about setting up pinning properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have testing for Debian, stable for Opera, but confusingly, although you've labeled it 'Opera repo', you're also using the Debian unstable repo.

I believe you're likely to end up with dependency issues when you mix repos like this. If you want to use software not available in your default repo, perhaps you should try backports?

This question shows more information about how to use the 'Default-Release' and APT Preferences to control which packages get pulled in:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8049/how-to-install-some-packages-from-unstable-debian-on-a-computer-running-stabl

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but maybe I am a bit confused. If we ignore the labels, and if I have both repos (testing and unstable), do I have a Debian Testing or Debian Sid install on my laptop? If I have switched to Sid, shall I reinstall or can I just switch to only Testing and wait for the packages to catch up on versions or ..?h

Comment: It'll probably be easier and cleaner just to reinstall. As Zoredache suggested above, you're now tracking 'FrankenDebian', which is a bad thing.